# Oracle APEX - Interactive Grid - Sorting Select List column on return value

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, interactive-grid

I have a Select List column in an Interactive Grid. It displays abbreviated days of the week (in Dutch):

- Ma - 1
- Di - 2
- Wo - 3
- Do - 4
- Vr - 5
- Za - 6
- Zo - 7

And so on...

If we now sort on this column, it is sorted on its display value rather than the return value.

I know that APEX uses an object to display this as follows:

```
{d: 'Ma', r: '1'}
```

Is it possible to sort a Select List column on its return value rather than the display value? And by sorting I mean clicking on the up or down arrows on the Interactive Grid Column Header:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why bother changing the rendered page ? It is a lot simpler to use a sql select statement as source for the select list. That gives you all the flexibility you want:

```
WITH dotw (dayabbr, nr) AS
(
SELECT 'Ma',1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Di',2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Wo',3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Do',4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Vr',5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Za',6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Zo',7 FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT 
  dayabbr AS d, 
  nr AS r FROM dotw 
ORDER BY nr

D   R
Ma  1
Di  2
Wo  3
Do  4
Vr  5
Za  6
Zo  7
```

Comment: I think this is the same solution provided by Ej Egyed;
Thanks for your answer, however, I believe this is sorting the actual LOV, not necessarily the records in the Interactive Grid based on the return value of the LOV. I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Hmm... I see your point, I'm not sure if that is possible. There are a couple of workarounds that you're probably aware of: (1) create a column with only the return value, order by that column, hide the column and save as default report. (2) add the return value to the display value - 1 - Ma, 2 - Di, etc but both are a bit clunky

Answer (score 0):

In the definition of your LOV (Shared Components > List of Values) you can define the order.

If you are using a static list of values, you would need to specify the Sequence column for the order that you want them to appear.

[image: Static LOV]

If you are using a dynamic LOV, you can specify the sort order that the list is rendered in.

[image: Dynamic LOV]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, I believe this is sorting the actual LOV, not necessarily the records in the Interactive Grid based on the return value of the LOV. I edited the question to make it more clear.